# Face topology for animated expressions?

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging, topology, retopology

I want to put this face on a sphere in a way where it can be animated, I know the topology needs to be clean for animation, do I need to retopo the whole sphere around the face, or is there a better way to go about that? Im also not sure the edge flow is correct.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: see [this thread](https://polycount.com/discussion/80005) and [this collection of examples](http://wiki.polycount.com/wiki/FaceTopology)

Answer (score 1):

The edge flow seems correct, now you could rotate your sphere 90° on X so that the pole is under your face. Once you've applied the *Shrinkwrap*, extrude all the outline of the mesh, make it circular, cut a hole in the sphere, join the face with the sphere.

Your current mesh, shrinkwrap it on the sphere:

[image]

Extrude its outline:

[image]

Apply the Shrinkwrap, join with the sphere, cut a hole in the sphere, bridge the 2 meshes:

[image]

Here is what it should give:

[image]